# How to control the flow in while and for loops?

Tags: python

I'm programming Clarke and Wright's savings algorithm to design vehicle routes from a depot to a set of customers. Right now, the code gets stuck in the final if statement if none of the conditions is met. What I want is that if ALL the cust_pairs have been checked and there is NO unserved cust_pair left which is either at the start or end of the previous route The code should break out of the second for loop. And then, go back to the first for loop to find a customer pair for starting a new route.

I've tried some things with 'break' and 'continue' but can not get it working.

```
def inPrevious(new,existing):
    start = existing[0]
    end = existing[len(existing)-1]
    if new == start:
        return 1
    elif new == end:
        return 0
    else:
        return -1

idx = -1

while not(allCustomersServed):

    for c in cust_pairs: 

        # find initial cust_pair with high savings
        idx += 1
        routes[idx] = ([c[0],c[1]]) 
        break

    #finding a cust that is either at the start or end of previous route

    for c in cust_pairs:
        # find feasible cust_pair that is either at the start or end of previous route    

        res = inPrevious(c[0], routes[idx])
        if res == 0:          
             # append c[1] to route          
        elif res == 1:
             # insert c[1] at position 0 in route   
        elif res == -1:
            res = inPrevious(c[1], routes[idx])
            if res == 0:
                # append c[0] to route   
            elif res == 1:
                # insert c[0] at position 0 in route
```

Comment: just add one more `else` condition with `break` after last `elif res == -1:` condition.

Comment: Are `append c[1] to route` and `insert c[1] at position 0 in route` supposed to be comment? Or this is just some sort of pseudo-code?

Comment: This is not the solution, because if I add this else condition, it will start a new route everytime that a cust_pair is not at the start or end of the previous route. However a new route should only be started if ALL the cust_pairs have been checked and there is no unserved left cust_pair which is either at the start or end of the previous route

Comment: Yes, should be comments. I edited the code.